# Is the afterlife mostly populated by embryos?

Tags: afterlife, immortality

Just about every branch of Christianity teaches the human soul becomes implanted in the embryo somewhere before birth.  Many branches also believe the human soul is immortal.

At the same time, I've read reports that as many as [60% of pregnancies end in miscarriage](https://www.newscientist.com/definition/miscarriage/).  This is in the context of our very developed medical system, historically speaking, so stands to reason the miscarriage rate was even higher in the past.

Altogether, does this imply that most of the immortal souls in the afterlife are embryos, at least according to the views of most Christians?

Comment: This is sheer speculation upon which scripture says nothing. The question is asking for opinions, which is off-topic on this site. God alone will judge of these matters and He alone knows what that judgment is.

Comment: It's a logical deduction from what most Christians believe.  How is that speculation?

Comment: It's only a logical conclusion according to what some Christians deduce.  According to other Christians, there can be no deduction based on Christian doctrine/teaching because such doctrine/teaching does not deal with embryos. Therefore, it can only ever be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Further, very many statistics include abortions in amongst the general heading of 'miscarriages'. This skews the figures to try to tone down just how massive the number of abortions have now become. SPUC honestly stated the statistic of 44.6 million unborn babies were aborted around the world in 2023. Despite a high miscarriage rate in centuries past, it's only been in the past 50 years or so that abortions account for a massive proportion of unborn babies/embryos. Nevertheless, we can only speculate about any immortal souls of such ones.

Comment: I know at least the Catholic church has always taught the embryo has an immortal soul after "quickening" and now seems to teach it has an immortal soul from conception.  The Catholic church accounts for a very significant chunk of Christians past and present.

Comment: It is sheer speculation for created men to speculate about the creation of a soul. Only the Creator knows.

Comment: The bible is pretty clear that creation of the soul happens at least before the baby is born.  Which still leaves a very significant portion of the afterlife populated by people who were never born.

Comment: @yters - I'm with you and the Catholic Church on this one.

Comment: @yters - I'm with CH Spurgeon on his views in his sermon "Infant Salvation" (free online) which includes the salvation of all who die in the womb.. though they have not consciously believed on Jesus because they cannot, yet they are regenerate and saved by the blood of Jesus.  All those conceived as human have eternal souls from the moment of conception.. this is far and away the most likely option.  Spurgeon also argues that the devil will not have the victory in terms of numbers in hell verses numbers in heaven.. Christ will be the Victor. Read his sermon to get a Reformed view.

Comment: @AndrewShanks yes, this would imply that heaven mostly consists of embryos, due to the high miscarriage rate.